# case insensitive search for non-indexed fields

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I search using case-insensitive filter without analyzing the data?
For e.g. in this example I get "delhi" and "Delhi" as separate entry because of capitalization.

```
new york 2
Delhi 1
delhi 1
new Jersey 1
```

Expected Results:

```
new york 2
delhi 2
new jersey 1
```

I tried lowercase analyzer, but for that I need to change the index to analyzed that will return "new" as a separate city and that is wrong.

```
DELETE /test_index
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "cities": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"cities":["new york", "delhi"]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"cities":["new york", "Delhi", "new Jersey"]}


POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "city_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "cities"
            }
}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you still need a `keyword` analyzer that does the exact same job as `not_analyzed` but only lowercases your input:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
     "analysis": {
       "analyzer": {
         "keyword": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "keyword",
           "filter": ["lowercase"]
         }
       }
     }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "cities": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Until ES 5, you can do this:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "city_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "script": "doc.cities.values.collect{it.toLowerCase()}"
            }
}}}
```

Comment: getting an error #"reason": "analyzer [analyzer] not found for field [cities]"

Comment: This time I do not get an error. But I still get the old wrong result. version #2.3.3

Comment: Ok, I see your issue. ES 5 will make it easy to do it, using [ingest nodes and the lowercase processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/lowercase-processor.html) you'll be able to transform your input before it gets indexed. Until then, you either need your client code to lowercase the terms before indexing the documents or to use an `terms` aggregation with script. I've updated my answer with the latter solution.

Comment: This shows delhi 2 correctly. But why does the other cities are not returned?

Comment: No problem, I've fixed it

Comment: can I use terms query like this? "terms" : { "cities" : ["delhi", "Delhi", "dElhi", "deLhi", "delHi", "delhI"]} I can write python code and generate all combinations per city - but Is this right approach to resolve case issue? Script is not supported by Amazon Elasticsearch service.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer (`filters` instead of `filter`), you can try again and use your original query (i.e. no need for scripting) and it will work, whatever the casing of your city names.

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the query that does not use scripting?

Comment: You can use the exact same query as in your original question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I used your mapping followed by my bulk and search query.